# 4 days error is here, Smart cast to 'Button!' is impossible, because 'generateOTPBtn' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: android, kotlin, one-time-password

have tried looking at past references, for this solution but seems am not getting it.
the code in question as below was originally in Java so Android Studio Arctic helped me convert it to Kotlin.
This is in pursuit to achieve or have a real working phone authenticating method for an application i want to build. Alternatively any tutorial link will be of great help.
the link where this was extracted is here [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/firebase-authentication-with-phone-number-otp-in-android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/firebase-authentication-with-phone-number-otp-in-android/)/
The lines with errors are 48, 50, 59, 65, 67 & 72.
My work environment is here

> Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Build
> #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021 Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation Windows 8 6.2 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
> Memory: 1280M Cores: 4 Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true Non-Bundled Plugins:
> org.jetbrains.kotlin

```
package net.nyange.busiro

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskExecutors
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //variable for FirebaseAuth class
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

    //variable for our text input field for phone and OTP.
    private var edtPhone: EditText? = null
    private var edtOTP: EditText? = null

    //buttons for generating OTP and verifying OTP
    private var verifyOTPBtn: Button? = null
    private var generateOTPBtn: Button? = null

    //string for storing our verification ID
    private var verificationId: String? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //below line is for getting instance of our FirebaseAuth.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        //initializing variables for button and Edittext.
        edtPhone = findViewById(R.id.idEdtPhoneNumber)
        edtOTP = findViewById(R.id.idEdtOtp)
        verifyOTPBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnVerify)
        generateOTPBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnGetOtp)



        //setting onclick listener for generate OTP button.

        generateOTPBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //below line is for checking weather the user has entered his mobile number or not.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhone.getText().toString())) {
                //when mobile number text field is empty displaying a toast message.
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Please enter a valid phone number.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                //if the text field is not empty we are calling our send OTP method for getting OTP from Firebase.
                val phone = "+256" + edtPhone.getText().toString()
                sendVerificationCode(phone)
            }
        })

        //initializing on click listener for verify otp button
        verifyOTPBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //validating if the OTP text field is empty or not.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtOTP.getText().toString())) {
                //if the OTP text field is empty display a message to user to enter OTP
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Please enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                //if OTP field is not empty calling method to verify the OTP.
                verifyCode(edtOTP.getText().toString())
            }
        })
    }

    private fun signInWithCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        //inside this method we are checking if the code entered is correct or not.
        mAuth?.signInWithCredential(credential)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //if the code is correct and the task is successful we are sending our user to new activity.
                    val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(i)
                    finish()
                } else {
                    //if the code is not correct then we are displaying an error message to the user.
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        task.exception.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
    }

    private fun sendVerificationCode(number: String) {
        //this method is used for getting OTP on user phone number.
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            number,  //first parameter is user's mobile number
            60,  //second parameter is time limit for OTP verification which is 60 seconds in our case.
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,  // third parameter is for initializing units for time period which is in seconds in our case.
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,  //this task will be executed on Main thread.
            mCallBack //we are calling callback method when we receive OTP for auto verification of user.
        )
    }

    //callback method is called on Phone auth provider.
    private val   //initializing our callbacks for on verification callback method.
            mCallBack: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks =
        object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            //below method is used when OTP is sent from Firebase
            fun onCodeSent(
                s: String?,
                forceResendingToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?
            ) {
                if (forceResendingToken != null) {
                    if (s != null) {
                        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken)
                    }
                }
                //when we receive the OTP it contains a unique id which we are storing in our string which we have already created.
                verificationId = s
            }

            //this method is called when user receive OTP from Firebase.
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                //below line is used for getting OTP code which is sent in phone auth credentials.
                val code: String? = phoneAuthCredential.smsCode
                //checking if the code is null or not.
                if (code != null) {
                    //if the code is not null then we are setting that code to our OTP edittext field.
                    edtOTP!!.setText(code)
                    //after setting this code to OTP edittext field we are calling our verified method.
                    verifyCode(code)
                }
            }

            //this method is called when firebase doesn't sends our OTP code due to any error or issue.
            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                //displaying error message with firebase exception.
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    //below method is use to verify code from Firebase.
    private fun verifyCode(code: String) {
        //below line is used for getting getting credentials from our verification id and code.
        val credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId.toString(), code)
        //after getting credential we are calling sign in method.
        signInWithCredential(credential)
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention which line the error is referring to. Having a guess though, if it's `verifyOTPBtn.setOnClickListener`, then it's because `verifyOTPBtn` is nullable. You'll have to either assert that it isn't, use the `?` operator, or declare it as `lateinit` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clearly explains the problem: as `generateOTPBtn` has type  `Button?`, the Kotlin compiler cannot guarantee that it won't be null, when you call `generateOTPBtn.setOnClickListener()`. The easiest workaround here is to replace

```kotlin
private var generateOTPBtn: Button? = null
```

with

```kotlin
private lateinit var generateOTPBtn: Button
```

Comment: hi, this surely worked. but others too seem to have that issue except they're inside the same block.

Comment: You can use the same tactics to deal with them. What is your problem now?